# CSS-only Dropdown (without popper.min)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the Dropdown component from here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#single-button

However I am trying to do CSS only.

The HTML is the copy from the docs:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" x-placement="bottom-start">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I added this style:

```
.dropdown:focus {
   display: block
}

.dropdown:focus .dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

However this isn't working. Would you recommend the checkbox hack over this one?

https://tutorialzine.com/2015/08/quick-tip-css-only-dropdowns-with-the-checkbox-hack

The problem with checkbox hack is it stays open until you click it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `div.dropdown` needs `tabindex` attribute to get focused.

Second, even if `div.dropdown` has a proper attribute and the button has been clicked, it is the button to get focused, not `div.dropdown`.

try below CSS:

```css
.dropdown>button:focus~.dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

working snippet:

```css
.dropdown>button:focus~.dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" x-placement="bottom-start">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you zmag! I ran your snippet, but it's not working. I accepted the answer though because things look right.